# ruby rails web request response lifecycle

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, web-applications

I'm a novice in ruby on rails trying to understand the in-depth flow of a typical request/response life cycle in ruby on rails web application.

I have googled for the info and have not found an answer which is complete or detailed to the level of DNS servers to dispatchers.

The closest I got to a good explanation is at:
http://brainspl.at/request_response.pdf.

Can someone point me to a better or more detailed explanation?

-Raviteja

Answer (score 11):

So you are asking for rails request/response cycle and you already referred to a presentation which really describes it very well. So im assuming that you want to know it from a very high level and you need this concept totally for development. Then here it is. Im just trying to name the parts sequentially.

1. **Route:** Here you will draw the paths which will be used by the world to access your application. With a complete RESTful architecture, you need to define the hierarchy of your resources and define how a resource can be accessed to perform some action. If any request to your application doesnt match with any path in the routes file, it will not be processed. If any match occurs, it will find the corresponding controller and action and will call it. At the time of calling, it will store all the request related data in `params` hash.
2. **Before Filters:** Now your application already know which controller#method is gonna process the request. And it will check if there is anything configured to execute before calling that method. This is done by using `before_filter`. If found anything then those functions will be called first.
3. **Method Execution:** After executing all the `before_filter` methods in a particular sequence, it will call the actual method. All the data is available in `params` hash in this method. It processes input data, invokes Model calls for database access, and prepare data for view.
4. **View:** Proper view file will be chosen based on the controller#action, format. Or you might select any particular view to render by `render :partial` call. And the response will be prepared using the variables prepared in controller. This response will go to the client.
5. **After Filters:** After processing the view, it will look `after_filter` methods and will those if found.

Well this was a quick overview i would say, without really any details. Im saying again, the pdf you referred really contains more details.

Let me know if you want to know anything more specifically.

Comment: What about before the routing system?  Is there a way to pre-empt the routing system?

Answer (score 3):

A user opens his browser, types in a URL, and presses Enter. When a user presses Enter, the browser makes a request for that URL.
The request hits the Rails router (config/routes.rb).
The router maps the URL to the correct controller and action to handle the request.
The action receives the request, and asks the model to fetch data from the database.
The model returns a list of data to the controller action.
The controller action passes the data on to the view.
The view renders the page as HTML.
The controller sends the HTML back to the browser. The page loads and the user sees it.

https://www.codecademy.com/articles/request-response-cycle-dynamic
and https://www.codecademy.com/articles/request-response-cycle-forms

Comment: And of course, there is a web server (such as nginx, apache etc.) between the Rails app and the HTTP client (web browser).

Answer (score 1):

Everything starts when ‘url’ requested by a user. The browser needs to know sever’s IP address to connect, So it lookup DNS(Domain name system) which translate your domain into the public IP address of the particular server. Then the Browser will do threeway handshake to connect server like puma in port 80. And decide upon public and private key it happen only because if url use HTTPS. HTTPS is a secure wrapper around HTTP and TCP. Then Server triggers the rails application through middleware like rack and provides request verb, header, body to the application. Then rails application use Journey (Default route library of rails) to find the consent controller and action which matches the request and call with the request and params.

Then rails lifecycle callbacks like before, after, around will be triggered during the process. The action takes care of requesting data from the model and rendering the consent view for the request. Finally sent back the status, header, and body as the response.

If you want to learn in-depth about lifecycle, check this article [The Lifecycle of a Request](https://blog.skylight.io/the-lifecycle-of-a-request/)

Answer (score 0):

It is also important to note that Rails apps use an `MVC architectural pattern`, which is **Model**, **View**, and **Controller** at a high-level the life-cycle of a request in rails app is simply the interaction of the **Model**, **View**, and **Controller**. This [article](https://medium.com/@matthewmain/rails-request-response-cycle-819e9cd8fa4e) gives you an overview.