# Ruby on rails data fetch to another controller's view

Tags: ruby-on-rails-4

I have two controllers and two view: homepage and joblist. 
I have a career.html.erb file and index.html.erb in homepage view. In career.html.erb, I have created a simple HTML form with labels and textboxes.

Homepage controller is a simple one with only view files. joblist controller is scaffolded. I have created jobs as well.

Now I just want my carrer.html.erb file form in homepage view to access and show in label the 'jobtitle' filed value of joblist controller.

Ho can I do that?

Answer (score 0):

It is bit tricky. Whenever user made a request to webpage from browser, rails server map that request to controller actions by using mapping defined in routes.rb file. Routing tells rails application this request is for what controller. Now rails engine instantiate that particular controller and call action method on that controller object. SO NO METHOD OR VARIABLE IS NOT AVAILABLE IN VIEW. You can only get variables from that particular action.

For more details [ruby rails web request response lifecycle](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12655604/ruby-rails-web-request-response-lifecycle)

Views are rendered by controllers. You set instance variables (variables started by @ sign) in controller and use these variables in view. So you need to set variables in same controllers from where you render views.

Comment: To elaborate a bit, think of the controller as facilitating the view of your model(s).  So, you really want to generate the `jobtitle` field from a particular `joblist` object in your `homepage` controller (e.g. `@jobtitle`) for action `career` and then you can reference that data in your view (`career.html.erb`).

Comment: In simple words, no action or action variable of other controller is available. To access other action method or its variable you need to redirect to that action.